# Changing the color of a container title for Android

Tags: java, android, xml, whatsapp, android-styles

I realize this might be an extremely stupid question, but I have no prior experience about java development in Android. I recently noticed that WhatsApp provided a [Sample App](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/master/Android) to create custom stickers and I wanted to use this as a stepping stone to get into developing.

Now I've run into the problem of wanting to change the title textcolor (I think) of the sticker packs. You can see what exactly I want to change in [this](https://i.imgur.com/1x99m9D.png) picture (I'm new here, so I can't post the picture directly, sorry).

As far as i can tell this tag in the *styles.xml* deals with the appearance of the sticker pack. The only thing I've added to the Sample project from WhatsApp is the last line to change the textcolor.

```
<style name="sticker_packs_list_item_author_style">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:lines">1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>
</style>
```

I believe it corresponds to this from the *StickerPackListItemViewHolder.java*, which I have not modified at all.

```
package com.example.samplestickerapp;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StickerPackListItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View container;
    TextView titleView;
    TextView publisherView;
    TextView filesizeView;
    ImageView addButton;
    LinearLayout imageRowView;

    StickerPackListItemViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        container = itemView;
        titleView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sticker_pack_title);
        publisherView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sticker_pack_publisher);
        filesizeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sticker_pack_filesize);
        addButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_button_on_list);
        imageRowView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sticker_packs_list_item_image_list);
    }
}
```

My added tag which I mentioned above seems to change the color of the publisherView and the filesizeView, but doesn't affect the titleView which I also want to change.

Ive tried using android:titleTextColor, android:textColorPrimary and android:textColorSecondary. None of those worked. I've been looking into this for hours now and was able to change the action bar and some other colors, icons and whatnot, but I can't figure this one out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `sticker_packs_list_item.xml` in layout has the `@+id/sticker_pack_title` TextView which sets `android:textColor="@android:color/black"` which is overriding the style - so either modify the textColor there or remove that attribute and control it with the style as you have been with others.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much, I would've never found that